# Как обрабатывать математическую функцию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, математика

В общем на вход будет вводиться математическое выражение, в котором будет вычисляться Y и есть X (при помощи цикла будет пробегаться по списку иксов и подставляться). После с помощью списков x-ов и y-ов будет построен график.
Как безопаснее всё это сделать? Подскажите

Comment: А у вас есть _опасное_ решение? Покажите ваш код.

Comment: Нет, кода пока что нет. Всё на уровнее теории. Можно было бы eval использовать, но придется делать ограничения, а это не круто, т.к. от всего сразу не сможешь отгородиться. Насчет совсем-совсем безопасного способа я преувеличил, но хотя бы какое-то годное решение можете подсказать? Может уже есть какая-то годовая годнота? Видел на js есть math.eval, дык может что-то подобное есть для питона

Comment: Вот, товарищ пишет про свой велосипед: ["evalidate: безопасная обработка пользовательских выражений"](https://habrahabr.ru/post/248117/)

Comment: Я бы сказал, вам нужен парсер арифметических выражений. Это непростая штука, и на шару не выйдет. Готовые парсеры есть, но в них синтаксис заранее фиксирован (а как иначе?), и у вас нет лёгкого пути подправить его. // Но раз в жизни написать свой парсер в любом случае надо.

Comment: Да, спасибо, буду пробывать)

Comment: related: [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2371436/4279)

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую взглянуть на [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/ru/)

Простой пример выражения:

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
func = parse_expr( "x + y" )
print( func ) #  x + y
print( func.args ) # x, y
x, y = func.args
print( func.n( subs={x:1, y:2} ) ) # 3.0000000
```